# Master-master / detail approach? (a.k.a, how to approach summarized data)

Tags: gui-design, master-details

Great day to everyone.

I'm trying to design an application that is basically a to-do list, which of course provides some level of master-detail: a list of tasks and the detail for each task.

Now, the extra feature that this application will provide will be a graph that displays dependencies between all tasks. And here's the challenge: since this generated graph is useful as a master view of the general list, it should be displayed as well.

So, I have two sections: a master overview, a master list (with add / remove capabilities) and a detail view.

How can these be designed so that it flows a naturally usable way?

This is what I have so far, which is not close to something that makes real sense to me.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYKTJl.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

What is the proper approach to this master-master-detail need? Or maybe there's no such thing as master-master-detail?

**Update:** After Izhaki's feedback I put together a second iteration where the upper panel is what actually gets displayed all the time: the list and the graph overview. The details panel gets hidden or shown if necessary to edit detail, so thanks to that it has become a more common master-details approach.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJxT1N.png)</sup>

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but consider only showing the delete button in edit mode. Providing an extra guard and interaction step to prevent slips. Assuming that it's always there when you edit (or create) a task, there's no problem it not being visible on the main screen - users *should* be able to recall that they have seen it before in edit mode.

Comment: @Izhaki Great tip! Thanks, I thought that would create discoverability issues, but if it's included the first time, then maybe it is not that bad.

Comment: Yeah. Delete-within-edit does not really follow common thinking because the two operations are clearly distinct ones. But the delete-within-edit is such a popular pattern in so many applications (notably that's how apple do it on the iPhone), that even if users don't see the delete button in edit mode many of them will guess it right. On that note, when creating a new entity, I actually think that a button labelled 'delete' is better that one labelled 'cancel'.

Comment: And although I'm pretty much certain you already have this in mind, adding task times would allow you to perform [critical path analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method), which would be a super-neat feature.

Comment: @Izhaki [On its way](https://github.com/AlphaGit/what-now/issues/5) ;)

Comment: Is it really necessary to show the WHOLE auto-generated graph in the graph view? Imagine a graph with 30 or 40 tasks, depending all over each other, odds are you cant represent the graph at some point in 2D without confusing the user, and graph wouldn't be dots any more but balls in 3D space to avoid connections crossing. Have you thought in changing or "zooming" the graph depending on the one selected? Something like when you select in the list-view the 4th task, you see in the center the 4th task, above it the ones in which the 4th depends, and below, the ones that depend on the 4th?

Comment: @khale912 Great feedback! I actually just updated the question with a second iteration that addresses some of those issues (zooming). Another incoming idea that is not present in the mockup is for the user to be able to select a subset of tasks in the graph and have the list auto-filtered to those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes likes this.

First, distinguish between the **data** and its **view**. In the case of the task *list*, you have one set of data, and two views to display it - if the data changes, both views need updating.

Then, consider these three popular IA concepts (I'm using my favourite terms, but mention other terms as well):

- **Unique component** - a component (typically a page) that only appears once in the system. For example, a [*privacy policy* page](http://www.gap.co.uk/customerService/info.do?cid=2331).
- **Listing component** (aka catalog, records, items, gallery) - a component that lists a collection of similar items. These typically involve a template and the entries are read from a database. For instance, [a page](http://www.gap.co.uk/browse/category.do?cid=57413&departmentRedirect=true#department=75) on a site listing all men T-shirts.
- **Record component** (aka item, product) - a component that shows a single record out of many. Typically a template page which populate the data of a single database record (and possibly its associations). For example, [a page](http://www.gap.co.uk/browse/product.do?cid=57442&vid=1&pid=000960455000) on a site showing a particular T-shirt.

Now in your case, you have a single set of data (the tasks) which has two views (the list and the graph), both are a form of listing component. This is common - like a travel information app that shows nearby stations both in a list form, and in a map form.

Then you also have a record component (a task), which is viewed by the task details panel.

I think what is glaring about the current design, is that you have chosen to create the following visual hierarchy:

- Left pane

  - Tasks (list view).
- Right pane

  - Tasks (graph view).
  - Task details.

Where it seems highly reasonable to employ the following structure.

- Left pane

  - Tasks (list view).
  - Tasks (graph view).
- Right pane

  - Task details.

In other words, move the graph you to the right (where the list view is) to take advantage of [gestalt law of proximity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology#Gestalt_laws_of_grouping).

If it is important for users to see both views at the same time, you should split the left panel to top and bottom parts. If it isn't, you can put each in a tab.

Also consider how important for users it is to permanently see the task details panel. Possibly you can show extra details on a popover box upon hover, and only show the form itself upon double click?

Comment: I loved this answer for providing me the thought process necessary to make the right calls. Thanks! It was important that users see both the list and the graph, and details are not as important, so I started with the concept of left: list, right: graph (note: the graph requires some big real state). However, the edit view would have to eventually be somewhere, so I went with the right panel since it's where I could take some space without hiding too much, but this lead me to what I have. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: (Sorry for the double comment) I've been rethinking on what you mentioned and maybe its not that important for users to see the table and the graph at the same time, as long as both provide the same functionality (even if it is in different ways). I'll play with that thought in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I can only guess, but given the highlighted item on the list, which also shows as a highlighted circle on the graph, I'd argue that it is very important to see both. I can easily see myself explore the graph by clicking on the list, or by clicking on the circles on the graph to see the related task. Quite an amazing concept in my view, and a highly attractive one.